# selecting between date range and forcing empty rows to be 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, datetime-generation

I have a table that looks like

```
expires    | value  
-------------------
2011-06-15 | 15  
2011-06-15 | 15  
2011-06-25 | 15  
2011-07-15 | 15  
2011-07-15 | 15  
2011-07-25 | 15  
2011-08-15 | 15  
2011-08-15 | 15  
2011-08-25 | 15
```

I want to run a query that will spit out

```
June   | 45  
July   | 45  
August | 45
```

So my query is

```
  SELECT SUM(amount) AS `amount`, 
         DATE_FORMAT(expires , '%M') AS `month`  
    FROM dealDollars 
   WHERE DATE(expires) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) 
                           AND LAST_DAY(DATE(NOW()+INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) 
GROUP BY MONTH(expires)
```

Which works fine.  But with the result, if there were no rows in say July, July would not show up.

How can I force July to show up with 0 as its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. One possible way is to have a table called months:
Which will have 12 rows: (January, February, ..., December)

You can left join the Months table with the query you have to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The general [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375235/generate-list-of-months-in-mysql) is that you should just create a table of month names. What follows is a silly solution which can serve as a workaround.

You'll have to work on the specifics yourself, but have you looked at [sub-queries in the from clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)?

Basically, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT NVL(B.amount, 0) as `amount`, A.month as `month`
      FROM (SELECT 'January' as `month`
            UNION SELECT 'February' as `month`
            UNION SELECT 'March' as `month`...
            UNION SELECT 'DECEMBER' as `month`) as A
      LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT SUM(amount) AS `amount`, 
                    DATE_FORMAT(expires , '%M') AS `month`  
               FROM dealDollars 
               WHERE 
                  DATE(expires) BETWEEN 
                       DATE(NOW()) AND 
                       LAST_DAY(DATE(NOW()+INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) 
               GROUP BY MONTH(expires)) as B
            ON (A.MONTH = B.MONTH)
```

Crazy, no?

Comment: Seriously, don't do that. Create a second table if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the `NUMBERS` table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.  In this case, the INSERT statement needs to be run at least 3 times.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of days, increasing based on the `NUMBERS.id` value:

   ```
   SELECT x.dt
     FROM (SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL (n.id - 1) MONTH)) AS dt
             FROM numbers n
            WHERE DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL (n.id - 1) MONTH)) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
                                                                                AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() +INTERVAL 3 MONTH))  ) x
   ```
4. Use an OUTER JOIN to get your desired output:

   ```
      SELECT x.dt,
             COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM (SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL (n.id - 1) MONTH)) AS dt
             FROM numbers n
            WHERE DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL (n.id - 1) MONTH)) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
                                                                                AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE() +INTERVAL 3 MONTH))  ) x
   LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE y ON y.date = x.dt
    GROUP BY x.dt
    ORDER BY x.dt
   ```

### Why Numbers, not Dates?

Simple - dates can be generated based on the number, like in the example I provided.  It also means using a single table, vs say one per data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select MONTHNAME(expires) as month_name,sum(`value`) from Table1
group by month_name order by null;
```

***[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57fa8/4)***